# aggregate query in mongoose mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

Hi I am trying the below query in my nodejs code

```
const totalCount = await model.countDocuments({
    'createdAt': { $gte: new Date(startDate), $lte: new Date(endDate) },
}).exec();

const activeCount = await model.countDocuments({
    'createdAt': { $gte: new Date(startDate), $lte: new Date(endDate) },
    'enabled': true,
}).exec();

const inactiveCount = (totalCount - activeCount);

return { totalCount, activeCount, inactiveCount };
```

Is there any way i can combine the above in a single query using aggregate in mongoose? Kindly guide me to the best solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, quite simple using some basic operators, like so:

```
model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: new Date(startDate),
        $lte: new Date(endDate)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalCount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      activeCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$enabled",
                true
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      totalCount: 1,
      activeCount: 1,
      inactiveCount: {
        $subtract: [
          "$totalCount",
          "$activeCount"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zd1MKngQYLJ)